# CSS3 animation not working only on Safari

Tags: animation, sass, safari, cross-browser

I know this question has been asked many times but my animation is different.

I gave multiple animations to one element using delay. Animation works perfect on all browsers except Safari.

Apparently, Safari wants the animation to be reversed. I tried this but failed. This is some lines of the code to show how I write the animation.

```
//first revealed text 
.has-line-anim-hidden-first {
 animation-name: lineScaleOut, lineToBottom, lineToTop, lineScale;
 animation-duration: $duration, $duration, $duration, $duration;
 animation-delay: 1.6s, 1.9s, 3.6s, 3.9s;
 animation-fill-mode: both, both, both, forwards;
 animation-timing-function: ease-out, ease-out, ease-out, ease-out;
}
```

Keyframes:

```
//Mixin
  @mixin keyframes ( $animation-name ) {
  @-webkit-keyframes #{$animation-name} {
    @content;
  }
  @-moz-keyframes #{$animation-name}  {
    @content;
  }
  @-o-keyframes #{$animation-name} {
    @content;
  }
  @keyframes #{$animation-name} {
    @content;
  }
} 

@include keyframes(reveal) {
  from {
   opacity: 0;
   }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@include keyframes(unreveal) {
  to {
   opacity: 0;
  }
 }

 @include keyframes(lineToTop) {
   to {
     bottom: 80%;
   }
  }

@include keyframes(lineToBottom) {
 from {
  bottom: 80%;
 }
 to {
  bottom: 0%;
 }
}

  @include keyframes(lineScale) {
   from {
  width: 100%;
  }
 to {
  width: 0;
 }
}

 @include keyframes(lineScaleOut) {
  from {
   width: 0;
   opacity: 0
}
  to {
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

**You can check all my code by [clicking this](https://codepen.io/shirinzadeh/pen/GRqwPXv)**

*What do I need to do to make the code work on the Safari?*

Comment: You should always properly tag your markup as SASS when you are using that.

Comment: Thank you. @Rob is my question understandable? How can I ask the question in a more accurate form?